# Conexión a base de datos MySql con PDO PHP

Tags: php, poo, pdo

Buenas estoy empezando en POO PHP y me encontré nuevas formas de conectarse a la base de datos y una de ellas es PDO quisiera saber si esta es una buena manera de conectarme o de plano esta mal o mejor aun si se podría mejorar

```
    <?php

   class DataBase{

      private $host;
      private $db;
      private $user;
      private $password;
      private $charset;

      public function __construct() {
         $this->host = constant('HOST');
         $this->db = constant('DB');
         $this->user = constant('USER');
         $this->password = constant('PASSWORD');
         $this->charset = constant('CHARSET');
      }

      public function conectar(){
         $conexion = "mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbnombre=" . $this->db . $this->db - ";charset=" . $this->charset;

         $opciones = [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
         ];

         $pdo = new PDO($conexion , $this->user, $this->password, $opciones);

         return $pdo;
      }
   }
?>
```

Comment: varias aclaraciones `PDO` no es una nueva manera de conectarse, sino una alternativa; por otro lado que tiene de mal este modo que ya usas? da problemas? no funciona? cual es la pregunta en si

Comment: si me funciona hasta ahora , lo que quiero saber es si es una manera optima porque ahi muchas cosas que funcionan , pero no siempre esta bien o es la mejor manera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// CONEXION PDO
class Conexion{

    public function conectar(){

        $usr  = "youruser";
        $pwd  = "yourpass";
        $host = "yourhost"; 
        $db   = "yourdb";
        try {
                    $link = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;", $usr, $pwd);

                    $link->exec("set names utf8");

                return $link;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Te dejo mi conexion PDO, es un poco más corta y no olvides añadir el utf8 si manejas tildes o ñ's en tu BD.

La que tienes esta bien, en el ejemplo que muestras defines mayor seguridad por el manejo de variables privadas y utilizar el constructor para llamar los datos de conexion y finalmente utilizas el $this para acceder a cada una de las variables, es por ello que se hace muy largo lo que manejas, pero de igual forma esta bien la conexion que utilizas.